# Java replacing characters in email with?

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

Here is my email implementation:

```
    private void send(Transport transport, Message message) throws MessagingException
    {
        // bunch of fluff
        transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
    }
```

But when my message body contains chars like `ş` and `“` are replaced with a `?`. I assume this has something to do with a char-set issue, but im not sure what to do about it.

Any help would be great.

Comment: Can be an encoding issue on your end, or during transport. Impossible to say with the little code you posted; we need a [mcve]. To troubleshoot, look at the source of emails where the characters are correct and compare to yours.

Comment: The characters you included are represented in UTF-8, but are not in ascii.  It seems likely that the @stdunbar is the answer you are looking for.  Note the "charset=utf-8" portion of the html mime body part

Comment: Looks like typical encoding issues,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I've had to do is to set the charset for the part.  I do something like:

```
Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(new Properties());
MimeMessage mimeMessage = new MimeMessage(session);
mimeMessage.setFrom(fromEmail);

mimeMessage.setSubject(subject, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());

MimeBodyPart plainTextMimeBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
plainTextMimeBodyPart.setText(plainTextMessage, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());

Multipart messageMultiPart = new MimeMultipart("alternative");
messageMultiPart.addBodyPart(plainTextMimeBodyPart);

MimeBodyPart htmlBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
Multipart relatedMultiPart = new MimeMultipart("related");

htmlBodyPart.setContent(htmlMessage, "text/html; charset=utf-8");

relatedMultiPart.addBodyPart(htmlBodyPart);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
  MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage();
  message.setText("ş and “", "UTF-8");
  // set recipients, etc

  send(transport, message);
```